# Suddenly getting error in Wpbakey plugin/ Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I am wokring on a theme in wordpress which contains visual composer and it was working perfectly last day. But today when i am trying to edit the page using visual composer frontend it keeps on loading and in backed when i click on save button nothing happens. So i check the chrome console and fond this error. Any help will be appriciated and thanks in advance i am attaching the error below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
at Object.defaults (frontend-editor.min.js:3)
at frontend-editor.min.js:7
at Function.m.each.m.forEach (load-scripts.php:97)
at Object.<anonymous> (frontend-editor.min.js:7)
at Object.getDefaults (frontend-editor.min.js:1)
at n.vcAddShortcodeDefaultParams (frontend-editor.min.js:1)
at _ (load-scripts.php:99)
at m (load-scripts.php:99)
at f (load-scripts.php:99)
at Object.u.trigger (load-scripts.php:99)
```

Comment: To help you better it would be great if you included the relevant part of your code that is throwing that exception, and any other relevant things to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert by any means but i have found the solution by myself so wanted to share the answer if it can help anybody. The problem was the PHP version. After I changed the PHP version of my server form PHP 7.1 to PHP 5.6 it solved the issue.